# Show that $f(x)=2x+\cos(x)$ is one-to-one.

Tags: calculus

Need hints as to how to show this without referring to its graph.

I tried setting $y=f^{-1}(x)$ and solving for $y$ in $x=2y+\cos(y)$, but I don't know how to go about doing it this way, if this is the right approach at all.

Comment: Hint: What property of the derivative of a function shows that the function itself is injective?

Comment: No you don't have to work out the inverse function.  It's enough to show that $y(x)$ is strictly monotonical in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(x)=2-\sin(x)\\f'(x)\in[1,3]$$ Hence f(x) is always an increasing function, so
$$f(x1)=f(x2) \implies x1=x2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ has a constant sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach by contradiction, without using differentiation.

---

Assume there exist two real numbers $x_1<x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then,

$$2x_1+\cos(x_1)=2x_2+\cos(x_2)\\\implies\cos(x_1)-\cos(x_2)=2(x_2-x_1)$$

Using an identity for the difference of cosines found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities),

$$-2\sin\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}2\right)=2(x_2-x_1)\\
\implies\sin\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2\right)=2\frac{\frac{x_2-x_1}2}{\sin\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}2\right)}$$

Knowing that $x>\sin(x)$ for all $x>0$,

$$\sin\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2\right)>2$$

Which we know to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

After differentiating  we get $f'(x)= 2-sin(x)$
 as we know that $-1< sin(x)<+1$ or min value of sin(x)=-1 or max value is +1 therefore $f'(x)>0$ Hence the function is strictly increasing, so $f(x)=2+cos(x)$ is **one to one**